# change the profile picture in twitter for every tweet

Tags: php, twitter

Is it possible to change the profile picture for every tweet via twitter api and it wouldnt change the profile pictures on the previous tweets?

for example:
i am going to tweet something good so i would want my profile picture to be something happy.

and then on my next tweet which seems to be something not good, i would like to change the profile picture to something sad.. and it wouldnt affect the profile picture of the previous tweet..

is it possible? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, your picture is tied to your user account, it's not stored with every tweet in any way.

When you change you picture it changes for all tweets, previous and current, this is simply a display thing in the UI and their APIs, not a property on the tweet, but on the user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the previous answer must have a grain of truth, but I don't think it's the whole truth (or maybe it was in 2010?).  I am currently able to change the pic, via the API, automatically on a per-tweet basis and it's definitely not the case that each pic-change overwrites the pic for all previous tweets.  To what extent Twitter is going to be able to store old pics and associate them with old tweets I do not yet know, but it's going to be interesting finding out...

Comment: This probably is dictated by your client, and it is merely caching the old tweets and the context they contained. I bet if you loaded a new client or had another user load your timeline for the first time you would see that all the pictures would be identical and would reflect your profile picture at the time of the load.